# Create a Tall formatted Dataframe from nested dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Hi I have a dictionary of dictionaries as shown (copied example). I would like to convert it into a tall `DataFrame`.

Example dictionary:

```
{'Jill': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,
         'Django Unchained': 6.5,
         'Gone Girl': 9.0,
         'Kill the Messenger': 8.0},
 'Toby': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5,
          'Django Unchained': 9.0,
          'Zoolander': 2.0}}
```

Expected tall dataframe look like below:

```
   Column1        Column2              Column3
    Jill     Avenger: Age of Ultron      7.0
    Jill     Django Unchained            6.5
    Jill     Gone Girl                   9.0
    Jill     Kill the Messenger          8.0
    Toby     Avenger: Age of Ultron      8.5
    Toby     Django Unchained            9.0
    Toby     Zoolander                   2.0
```

I tried the below, it gives me main keys of dictionaries as first column, but couldn't make it as tall dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

Comment: You could use a simple dictionary comprehension to parse this starting with a concat statement `pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in yourDict.items()}, axis=0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d = {'Jill': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,
                            'Django Unchained': 6.5,
                            'Gone Girl': 9.0,
                            'Kill the Messenger': 8.0},
'Toby': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5,
                                'Django Unchained': 9.0,
                                'Zoolander': 2.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d).reset_index()
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=["index"], 
                  var_name="By", value_name="Score").dropna()
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple way would be to convert the dictionnary to a list of lists and feed the dataframe with that:

```
data = [[x, y, z] for x,v in d.items() for y, z in v.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Column' + str(i) for i in range(1,4)])
```

It gives:

```
  Column1                 Column2  Column3
0    Jill  Avenger: Age of Ultron      7.0
1    Jill        Django Unchained      6.5
2    Jill               Gone Girl      9.0
3    Jill      Kill the Messenger      8.0
4    Toby  Avenger: Age of Ultron      8.5
5    Toby        Django Unchained      9.0
6    Toby               Zoolander      2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ratings = {'Jill': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 7.0,
                    'Django Unchained': 6.5,
                    'Gone Girl': 9.0,
                    'Kill the Messenger': 8.0},
           'Toby': {'Avenger: Age of Ultron': 8.5,
                    'Django Unchained': 9.0,
                    'Zoolander': 2.0}}
values = [[name, movie, rating] for name, r in ratings.items() for movie, rating in r.items()] 
df = pd.dataframe(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass to the `DataFrame` , all the rest we handle in `pandas`

```
pd.DataFrame(ratings).reset_index().melt('index').dropna()
Out[118]: 
                    index variable  value
0  Avenger: Age of Ultron     Jill    7.0
1        Django Unchained     Jill    6.5
2               Gone Girl     Jill    9.0
3      Kill the Messenger     Jill    8.0
5  Avenger: Age of Ultron     Toby    8.5
6        Django Unchained     Toby    9.0
9               Zoolander     Toby    2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using the `pandas.DataFrame` constructor on the `dict` as is, then [stacking](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [renaming](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) and sorting the [axis](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and [columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = (pd.DataFrame(d)
      .stack()
      .reset_index()
      .rename({'level_0': 'Column2', 'level_1': 'Column1', 0: 'Column3'}, axis=1)
      .sort_index(1).sort_values('Column1'))

print(df)


  Column1                 Column2  Column3
0    Jill  Avenger: Age of Ultron      7.0
2    Jill        Django Unchained      6.5
4    Jill               Gone Girl      9.0
5    Jill      Kill the Messenger      8.0
1    Toby  Avenger: Age of Ultron      8.5
3    Toby        Django Unchained      9.0
6    Toby               Zoolander      2.0
```